# TYPO3 imagemagick makes images oversaturated

Tags: imagemagick, typo3

My images come out oversaturate. I didn't change the the default configuration.
I'm using TYPO3 8.7 and imagemagick 6.7.2-7. Is this a TYPO3 thing?
[image]

Comment: If your images are CMYK, you would be better to convert using profiles for better color results. Your command line is very small and hard to read It would be better if you posted it as text. Also it would be helpful if you provided your input image separately so we can test processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are not over saturated but darker. A known error which is mentioned in the install_tool.

in the install tool change the value for

```
[GFX][processor_colorspace]
```

from `sRGB` to `RGB`